# On very basic Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

My understanding of Lebesgue integration is still lacking, so I'd like to start understanding better with a simple question:

Let $f(x)=0$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and 1 otherwise. Let $\mu$ be a measure such that $\mu(\{y\})=\frac{1}{2}$ if $y=1$ or 2 (i.e. similar to flipping a coin) and thus $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$.

If I want to find $\int fd\mu$, is it 1 because $f(x)=1$ nearly everywhere? Or is it 0 because $f(x)=0$ at $x=1$ and 2? Or something different altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}-\{1,2\}$ has measure zero,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \,d\mu=\int_{\{1,2\}}f\,d\mu=\int_{\{1\}}f\,d\mu+\int_{\{2\}}f\,d\mu=f(1)\mu(\{1\})+f(2)\mu(\{2\})=0$$
The fact that $f(x)=1$ nearly everywhere with respect to the Lebesgue measure is irrelevent here because $\mu$ is *not* the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: I'm incredibly new to Lebesgue integration. Is $\mathbb{R}-\{1,2\}$ the same as $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2\}$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Yes.